# Android scaling down image always ends up stretched

Tags: android, imageview, image-resizing

I am trying to scale down a high res image like around 1980x1080 size and I'm emulating in nexus 5 API 21+, I need to load this high res image into my image view holder.

I am using the below bitmap code

```
float imageRatio = (float) newWidth / newHeight;

int imageWidth = mybitmapimage.getWidth();
int imageHeight = mybitmapimage.getHeight();

float aspectRatio = (float) imageWidth / imageHeight; // original iamge

// Initializing to find which needs scale down
float scaleWidth = newWidth;
float scaleHeight = newHeight;

if (imageRatio < aspectRatio) {
    scaleHeight = ((float) newWidth) / aspectRatio;
} else {
    scaleWidth = ((float) newHeight) * aspectRatio;
}

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// RESIZE THE BIT MAP

matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        bm, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, matrix, false);
return resizedBitmap;
```

For the life of me, this code always ends up with either getting stretched or cropped. The source image file is around 1920*1080 so its a scale down.

If anyone could help me with this twisting problem of mine, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: obviously scaleWidth and scaleHeight should be the same. If you passes differend values, your image will be scalled differently along x and y axes.

Comment: yes i agree to that, but how do i prevent stretching ? like its width gets stretched while trying to fit height, and if the height and width seem ok, the image like positioned in the center and black background around it..                   I tried fitXY and all the other scale options in scaletype available, nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you want your image just to fit whole area (without maintaining the proportion) you can just calculate scaleWidth = newWidth / oldWidth; scaleHeight = newHeight / oldHeight;  I cannot figure out what your calculations are doing.

Comment: I actually did that                                                                                                        scaleHeight = ((float) newWidth) / oldwidth;                                                            scaleWidth = ((float) newHeight) / oldHeight;                                                                                  but even that ended up up being stretched on with width of the screen

Comment: check "width" and "height" may be there was a misprint, like in your comment.

Comment: Ah nah mate... .it aint, i typed it in the comment so didnt realize it.

Comment: @Wildcopper how do i use it mate in the bitmap function bro ?

Comment: Posted an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

```
ratio = Math.min(newWidth/oldWidth, newHeight/oldHeight);
```

That's how you get a scaling ratio to resize a bitmap while keeping the aspect ratio.

The final width and height are then:

```
finalWidth = oldWidth * ratio;
finalHeight = oldHeight * ratio;
```

Just use that ratio in your scale matrix:

```
matrix.postScale(ratio, ratio);
```